# iOS: How to send localized contact name directly in PUSH notification like Viber

Tags: ios, iphone, push, contacts, placeholder

In the Viber app, I often receive alerts saying "[contact_name] is now using Viber". where [contact_name] is the name of a contact as I have saved in my address book.

This means that viber has a way of inserting contact names from my address book directly in a PUSH notification alert JSON. How is this done?

I have read https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

But I am still at a loss as to how Viber does this or if this is some trick with local push notifications etc.. It is often the case that I receive this after not using Viber for a long time so I don't think it can come as a local notification. Any ideas?

Comment: I imagine they have uploaded all of your contacts to their server and then match new users using their email address. They can then insert the information from their database into the push message

Comment: That would mean uploading the contact name/number pairs for the whole contact list of every user, which for Viber equates to around 250 billion database entries(500 million users x (average) 500 contacts per user) ... I doubt it.

Comment: I don't doubt it - 100 bytes for a name and 100 bytes for an email address and 100 bytes for phone numbers is less than 200 terabytes